# How to hide loader after elements under a div tag are fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever I click a load-more button, I wanna show a loader. If everything from the load-more feature is loaded under a div tag, I wanna hide the loader.

I've done some research about it, but they didn't really help. This is what I've done so far. Can anyone help about this?

**Javascript**

```
$('.load-more-btn').on('click', function() {
    var spinner = $('.spinner')
    var loadBtn = $(this)

    spinner.removeAttr('hidden')
    loadBtn.hide()

    if ($('.wrapper-children').length > 0) {
      loadBtn.delay(1000).show(0)
      spinner.hide()
    }

  })
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper-children">
  <!-- Additional contents by Ajax will come here -->
  <div class="spinner" hidden>
    <span class="inner"></span>
    <span class="inner"></span>
    <span class="inner"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="...">
  <a class="load-more-btn">View More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I did it

Used `setTimeout()` since I use it for its callback. Alternative would be to use `delay(1000).queue()`.

Load this [`.gif`](https://www.bikearena-bender.de/.resources/bulls-templating/img/system/preloader.gif) using `CSS`.

If using `$.ajax()`, you would disable the gif on `success: function(){}`

```js
$('.load-more-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.spinner').css('visibility', 'visible');
    
    $(this).hide()
    if ($('.wrapper-children').length > 0) {
     $(this).hide();
      
      // setTimeout is global and supports callbacks
      // () => {} is an arrow-function
     setTimeout(() => {
        $(this).show();
        $('.spinner').css('visibility', 'hidden')
      }, 1000);
      
    }
  })
```

```css
.spinner {
  content: ' ';
  background: transparent url('https://www.bikearena-bender.de/.resources/bulls-templating/img/system/preloader.gif')  center no-repeat ;
  background-size : auto 100%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper-children">
  <!-- Additional contents by Ajax will come here -->
  <div class="myContainer">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
    <span class="inner"></span>
    <span class="inner"></span>
    <span class="inner"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="...">
  <a class="load-more-btn">View More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I ask you why you added `<div class="myContainer">`?

Comment: I usually prefer to wrap more than one thing inside a ‘div’ so both elements are contained together for future ‘css’ control.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

**Javascript**

```
$('.load-more-btn').on('click', function() {
    var spinner = $('.spinner')
    var loadBtn = $(this)

    spinner.removeAttr('hidden')
    loadBtn.hide()

    if ($('.wrapper-children .dynamic-content').length > 0) {
      loadBtn.delay(1000).show(0)
      spinner.hide()
    }

  })
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper-children">
  <!-- Additional contents by Ajax will come here-->
  <div class=“dynamic-content”>I’m loaded by ajax</div>
  <div class=“dynamic-content”>I’m loaded by ajax too</div>
  <div class=“dynamic-content”>These ‘dynamic-content’ divs won’t exist if they aren’t being loaded by ajax</div>
  <div class="spinner" hidden>
    <span class="inner"></span>
    <span class="inner"></span>
    <span class="inner"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="...">
  <a class="load-more-btn">View More</a>
</div>
```